# Should I consider mobile browser virtual viewports a systemic bug or are there effective workarounds?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, viewport, android-browser

Most browsers on mobile devices are using a virtual viewport that does not match the real display. There are several reasons why this is useful, the most important I think are:

- A small device may seem large enough for a usual old school web page to not break it's layouts meant for desktop screens.
- It is used to get the HTML render engine render more than the currently visible part of the page, thus enabling smooth scrolling and zooming.

However, this breaks several standardized behavour expectations I think.

- In particular, the page is not aware of its visible area, thus JS powered things like popups or notifications don't work correctly anymore.
- It seems to break on-demand loading of embedded ressources (like thumbnails, video objects, endless lists) if the user move the element into view.
- It also introduces erratic behavour with layout adpating JS, for example onresize Handlers adpating the page's layout could easily change the pages size, thus resizing the viewport maybe even repeat triggering the onresize event.

Should I consider this as yet-broken-but-someday-fixed behavour and stick to small workarounds in every broken page, or should I drop any expectaions on onresize, window.innerWidth etc. and go back to more static layouts not relying on the idea of a viewport anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to weigh up the development cost of trying to figure out all the quirks vs. supporting all the devices/screen sizes you want to target. I'm facing a similar question, its certainly an interesting challenge! [Web app on android browser WIDTH issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541712/web-app-on-android-browser-width-issue)